# How to set the MediaRecorder to get the best video quality effect?

Tags: java, android, encoding, camera

Guys can someone tell me how should I set the parameters in the `MediaRecorder` in order to get the best video recording effect possible through coding without considering the physical limitation of the phone? Or is there any effect of the view small distortion caused by my coding of the `MediaRecorder`?

If some of you might be guessing of the unclear parameters I'm actually setting some of the parameters using preferences. What are the parameters I miss which might help to improve the video encoding process Ex: framerate

Comment: Are talking about quality? This varies from device to device based on the underlying codecs and the camera, but try changing the video encoder to H264 and increasing the resolution see if that helps..

Comment: @Ravi hey just to make confirm which part of my code really handle encoding and resolution?

Comment: You will have to set the resolution using `void  setVideoSize(int width, int height)` and encoding `public void setVideoEncoder (int video_encoder)` on the MediaRecorder class instance. Check the MediaRecorder documnetation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Depending on the API level you may want to use existing profiles or not.

Without profiles:

```
recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); //might be auto-determined due to lighting
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Or if you want to use existing profiles

```
CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
```

Please note that you cannot have both options together as you will get errors or your prepare will not work

As not all the Android API and/or devices support the same values you will either have to query the maximum values per device or find something that works everywhere.

Comment: Note: You have to remove `setOutputFormat()`, `setVideoEncodingBitRate()`, `setAudioEncodingBitRate()`, `setVideoEncoder()`, `setAudioEncoder()`, `setAudioSamplingRate()`, `setVideoFrameRate()`

Comment: is CamcorderProfile built in somehwre? not defined in chrome windows 7 (almost) latest version

Answer (score 7):

Although the question is quite old, i would like to to point out the combination i used to record the video of HD quality.

Use below combination of the code to achieve HD quality video.

```
CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);                    
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);                        
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);                        
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);                    
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);                    
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);                    
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(cpHigh.videoBitRate);                    
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cpHigh.videoFrameRate);
int rotation = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
```

Use below code to get the DISPLAY_HEIGHT,DISPLAY_WIDTH

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();      
mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);          
DISPLAY_WIDTH = metrics.widthPixels;
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Define ORIENTATIONS as shown below

```
public static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what is the ORIENTATIONS variable ?

Comment: @Vodet please check the updated code..sorry for delayed response

Comment: The problem with this is, you don't know if the device supports the video size provided @ `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH`.

Comment: What about high quality audio?

Comment: @mickecast the quality dont have any visible difference.

Comment: Hello @divaPrajapati09