# Android mediarecorder only recording terrible quality video

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, video-capture, video-processing, mediarecorder

So I have the following code to do my recording and the quality is absolutely terrible. I think I must have a setting wrong but I have tried it both ways. The "CamcorderProfile" way and then "Manual" way, you can see the camcorder code is commented out. Both give the exact same results.

```
    Camera _camera = Camera.Open (1);
    _camera.Unlock ();

    recorder = new MediaRecorder ();

    recorder.SetCamera (_camera);

    recorder.SetAudioSource (AudioSource.Mic);    
    recorder.SetVideoSource (VideoSource.Camera); 

    recorder.SetOutputFormat (OutputFormat.Default);

    recorder.SetAudioEncoder (AudioEncoder.Default);
    recorder.SetVideoEncoder (VideoEncoder.Default);

    //CamcorderProfile p = CamcorderProfile.Get(0, CamcorderQuality.High);
    //recorder.SetProfile(p);

    recorder.SetOutputFile (path);       

    recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(video.Holder.Surface);

    recorder.Prepare ();
    recorder.Start ();
```

And this works just fine, but here is the issue. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvM6G.jpg) is a picture of the preview window when I am recording, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9caR.png) is picture of the video when I play it back. You cant actually tell because the screenshot is so terrible, but none of the colors are right either (it has almost no color) I think there must be some sort of issue with the color channels. For example here is another comparison with the genymotion "dummy camera" . Here is the [correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1bIr.png) version. And here is the [weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeIEJ.png) playback version.

Comment: Have you tried [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058839/how-to-set-the-mediarecorder-to-get-the-best-video-quality-effect)

Comment: tried what? I tried the code I posted and the results are what is below the code.

Comment: @CalvinMoss, blue text is a hyper link. Click it to see what he's referring to.

Comment: late to the party....but still someone might find this useful.. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51961780/5312599

Answer (score 5):

This property helps in improving video quality:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);  //you may try varying the argument value
```

and ofcourse call this method before prepare() :)

Comment: 1 minute video = ~31mb using a bit rate of 3000000

Answer (score 3):

[This is a working example using the following configuration:](http://android-er.blogspot.hk/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html)

```
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getExternalStorageDirectory() + "myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
```

However if you use Android 5 you should use the new camera [API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Media).