# How can I set VideoEncodingBitRate in android?

Tags: android

I have set `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize`.

I hope to get high, medium and low video quality effect via `setVideoEncodingBitRate()`. What value should I set for high, medium and low quality when I invoke the function `setVideoEncodingBitRate()` ?

Is `recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000)` high quality? How can the value 3000000 be calculated?

And I don't want to use `CamcorderProfile`.

BTW, I have read the document [How to set the MediaRecorder to get the best video quality effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058839/how-to-set-the-mediarecorder-to-get-the-best-video-quality-effect)

Comment: Did you find the values that should be set for Low, Medium and High?

Answer (score 2):

Without profiles:

```
recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); //might be auto-determined due to lighting

recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);

recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP

recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Or if you want to use existing profiles

```
CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
```

Please note that you cannot have both options together as you will get errors or your prepare will not work

As not all the Android API and/or devices support the same values you will either have to query the maximum values per device or find something that works everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! but your anwser is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058839/how-to-set-the-mediarecorder-to-get-the-best-video-quality-effect

Comment: My question is  "What value should I set for high, medium and low quality? and I don't wish to use CamcorderProfile."

Comment: You need to change the value for recorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);  as per your quality.

Comment: Thanks, I need to set recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate() to get different quality. BTW, I have set MediaRecorder.setVideoSize!

Comment: @HelloCW If you satisfy with my answer please vote up to support me.

Comment: I hope to know what value I should set for high, medium and low quality when I invoke the function VideoEncodingBitRate.