# Select Video Quality like YouTube in Android

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I want to make a sample Android app where I will get a video URL from the server and I have to play video in `VideoView`. That has been achieved. Now I want to put a button in `VideoView` where I can select Video Quality like

[YOUTUBE Stream Quality Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKZV.jpg)

My Code for VideoView is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

VideoView simpleVideoView;
MediaController mediaControls;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    simpleVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.simpleVideoView);

    if (mediaControls == null) {
        // create an object of media controller class
        mediaControls = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        mediaControls.setAnchorView(simpleVideoView);
    }
    // set the media controller for video view
    simpleVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
    // set the uri for the video view
    simpleVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.fishvideo));
    // start a video
    simpleVideoView.start();

    // implement on completion listener on video view
    simpleVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // display a toast when an video is completed
        }
    });
    simpleVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops An Error Occur While Playing Video...!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // display a toast when an error is occured while playing an video
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

**I want to load Video based on Stream Quality Selection. Please guide me. Any sample code for Library would be great**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058839/how-to-set-the-mediarecorder-to-get-the-best-video-quality-effect

Comment: @NileshRathod thnxx for quick response.Is there any sample code where I can customize video view  or any third party library ?

Comment: Use exoplayer and there is a class TrackSelection which help you to choose bitrates from given URL. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: @andy https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-x-track-selection-2b62ff712cc9

Comment: @GeorgePJ Thank you so much for your help. I am going to implement this Library.

Comment: @andy then mark it as useful :)